# How to send object/state to whole application/all fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an app, where there is a searchbox in Main Activity and bottom navigation. In searchbox, the user choose te location, then sends the query to the weather API. I want to pass the object, which is the response from the API, to all fragments in my app. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: you want to pass data from activity to fragment or fragment to fragment?

Comment: you can also explore event bus

Comment: if you are using this into whole app than the best one to store the Response model into local data base like room,Realm, or shared prefrence and use its any where in the app , and if you want less than 3 or 4 screen than just pass thrugh intent or bundel the whole response model

Comment: From Activity to Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a `ViewModel` to store your data. Also, using `MutableLiveData` you can dynamically update your UI to the changes of the model.
2. Use RxJava to create an `EventBus` object, which can hold an `BehaviorSubject` with the latest published data. Again, you can subscribe to this data and update your UI automatically.
3. Use a Room or Realm to store data, if you need the location between multiple app sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have several options:

1. To save received data into the local database (you can use Room from Jetpack). And then to load the data from the database to the screen you need separately.
2. Or you can save the data into memory: it can be something like a DI container.
3. Also, you can use RxJava caching or Retrofit caching.

The second solution is the simplest for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send whole object through this in your application and access it anywhere you want to

- Step 1:
  Store your data in list you want to like:

  ```
  ArrayList<FeaturedProductDataModel> featuredProductsDataModelArrayList;
             ///////////get data and store in ArrayList///////////////////
       featuredProductsDataModelArrayList = new ArrayList<(listofhome.getFeaturedProducts());
  ```
- Step 2:
  Declare Shared Preference and put data in it to further use in all application

  ```
    featuretopprefernce = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("homelist", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ```

SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = featuretopprefernce.edit();

//Set the values

Gson gson = new Gson();

String listofbusiness = gson.toJson(featuredProductsDataModelArrayList);
prefsEditor.putString("featuredProductsDataModelArrayList", listofbusiness);

prefsEditor.apply();

- Step 3:

In recieving activity or fragment create a list and put data in it

```
ArrayList<FeaturedProductDataModel> dataModelArrayList;

SharedPreferences featuredprefernce;

featuredprefernce = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("homelist", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            featuredlist  = featuredprefernce.getString("featuredProductsDataModelArrayList",null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<FeaturedProductDataModel>>(){}.getType();
            dataModelArrayList  = gson.fromJson(featuredlist, type);
```

You'll get your data in dataModelArrayList now use it as you like.